# How to build square boxes using Bootstrap Panels

Tags: html, css, jsp, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
 <div class="row">
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
 </div>
```

how can I add these boxes inside dashboard div using bootstrap?

I was trying

```
 <div class = "panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-sm" style="padding: 5px 15px;">Statistics</div>
        </div>
```

However, I'd want them to be square on the inside so that I can include information about the task list.

Comment: A fiddle would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a fixed height and width for square
or you can either do

```
<div class="box">data</div>
```

css :

```
.box
{
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

and all child should be position: absolute .

Comment: Thanks, but do you how can I set the space between boxes?

Comment: give margin to each box {margin: 10px}.